# Locate iPhone without an internet connection

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to desperately locate my lost iPhone 4 (factory unlocked). It does not have an Internet connection—no 3G, no 4G and it is not in a Wi-Fi zone. The bell rings when I call which means that SIM is the same and battery has some juice left.

Can somebody please help?

Comment: Do you mean when you call it, you hear the ringer? If so, follow the sound!

Comment: @DanielLawson: I think he means when he calls it, he hears it ring on the other end of the call (not in person, but through the speaker of the phone he's calling it from).

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately with today's technology it is not possible to locate your iPhone, if it has no connection to the internet of any kind.

Answer (score 2):

Technically it is possible to locate a cell phone based on the IMEI number, but only your carrier can do that, and I assume in most parts of the world it requires a police or court order to do so.

Comment: Even without cellular connectivity?

Comment: No, but OP specified there is cellular connectivity.

Comment: "It does not have an Internet connection. That is, **no 3G**, no 4g and it is not in a wi-fi zone." The wording is a bit funny because it refers to Internet connectivity, but I think the OP is saying it's got zero connectivity at all.

Comment: I think he means the dial tone ringing, though. Because if he could hear the device itself ringing, then it wouldn't be lost.

Comment: If the dial tone is ringing, that implies the phone (or at least the SIM card) has cellular connectivity, else the call would go straight to voicemail.

Comment: ...Hmmmmm... This is very true. OP needs to clear up a few things about the post.

Comment: Agree with this, your carrier can help you find your phone without internet connection. I heard rumor this is how police track call number :)